# PhpStorm JavaScript method defined in ob_start php in other JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

How can I recognize JavaScript method defined in `ob_start()` php in other JavaScript project files?

Consider the following situation:

file1.php

```
<?php 
function js_functions(){
    ob_start();?>
    <script>
        function add(a,b){
            return a+b;
        }
    </script>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

file2.js

```
console.log(add(3,5));
```

The **`add()` function** is not recognized by PhpStorm -- how can I force PhpStorm recognize this function?

Comment: have you called `js_functions` and is it before you include the file2.js?

Comment: Yes I'm using the function easily as it is well included, but phpStorm does not recognize this function and and says **unresolved** function!

Comment: AFAIK each `<script>` tag in IDE is treated as separate/own document and stuff from here is not visible to the rest of files. Your best option is to have it declared in actual `.js` file -- this way it will be visible elsewhere.

Comment: I know, you are right about seperating to a `.js` file,
but this way I have a integrated file coding

Comment: Well ... in such case I may only suggest this (just to satisfy IDE -- this will not be used by actual site): create separate .js file and place it anywhere in your project (e.g. `/root/_ide_helpers/` folder) and put such function declaration there -- no need for a function body (it will be empty) -- this should be enough for IDE to recognize it and offer in code completion. If not -- you can declare such file as a [JavaScript Library](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/) and tell where it should be used for code completion.

Answer (score 1):

as @LazyOne mentioned, each injected fragment is currently a separate document, thus functions defined in these fragments are not available in others. Please follow [WI-3696](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3696) for updates.